# Closure table equivalent for graph structures in SQL

Tags: sql, database, hierarchical-data, transitive-closure-table

This question [How to store tree structure in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690193/how-to-store-tree-structure-in-sql) lead to the idea of a [Closure table](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) for storing trees that is optimal in many ways.

[image]
[image]

The question is is there something along these lines for graph structures in SQL. I saw [this paper](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~dbl/papers/he_icde_2006.pdf) which seems to outline a graph index structure but it's a bit over my head. Wondering if there is a sort of way to create a few auxiliary tables to handle common queries on graph data in SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closure Table INSERT statement including the level/distance column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622698/closure-table-insert-statement-including-the-level-distance-column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did the presentation you linked to, and I've been asked about implementing general graphs with a similar method, but I've never gotten around to it.

Certainly there are problems with the technique if you have cyclic graphs, unless you can unambiguously identify a "starting node." Because otherwise if you start with any node in a cycle, you'd want to be able to traverse the whole cycle in the graph.

It might be easier in SQL using a recursive CTE, but I most often use MySQL which doesn't support CTE syntax until version 8.0. And if you do have recursive CTE capability, you'd be better off using that instead of a closure table, because you have less chance for data anomalies.

Another option is to explore a specialized [graph database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database). For MySQL/MariaDB, there's a community storage engine that optimizes for tree and graph queries: https://openquery.com.au/products/graph-engine

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would like to avoid graph databases and see how this would work in SQL without any special help (like you're saying you use, would love to see an example). Yeah I was wondering if the graph was highly connected with lots of cycles what would happen, is it even possible to have a runtime dynamic SQL table(s) to handle it, etc.

Comment: `oqgraph` is 9 years  old!  I could find no newer version than 2009